# iframe scroll bars are not displaying in chrome after hide and show the iframe element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

The scroll bars on the iframe element is not showing when iframe element is hide and show it again.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
<iframe id="imageFrame" scrolling="yes" src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/the_legend_of_zelda_elf_shield_sky_link_22301_1280x1024.jpg" width="100" height="100">

</iframe>
<button id="hideFrame">
Hide Frame
</button>
<button id="showFrame">
Show Frame
</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hideFrame").click(function() {
    $("#imageFrame").hide();
  });

  $("#showFrame").click(function() {
    $("#imageFrame").show();
  });
});
```

**JSFIDDLE DEMO:**
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hollykarthi2016/17knnLsb/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

HTML:

```
<iframe id="imageFrame" scrolling="yes" src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/the_legend_of_zelda_elf_shield_sky_link_22301_1280x1024.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</iframe>
<button id="hideFrame">
    Hide Frame
</button>
<button id="showFrame">
    Show Frame
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.hide{visibility: hidden;position: absolute;}
.show{visibility: visible;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hideFrame").click(function() {
    $("#imageFrame").addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
  });

  $("#showFrame").click(function() {
    $("#imageFrame").addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/17knnLsb/7/

---

Solution 2:

HTML:

```
<div class="iframe-wrapper"></div>
<button id="hideFrame">
    Hide Frame
</button>
<button id="showFrame">
    Show Frame
</button>
```

jQuery:

```
var iframeMarkup = '<iframe id="imageFrame" scrolling="yes" src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/the_legend_of_zelda_elf_shield_sky_link_22301_1280x1024.jpg" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.iframe-wrapper').append(iframeMarkup);
  $("#hideFrame").click(function() {
    $('.iframe-wrapper').find('iframe').remove();
  });

  $("#showFrame").click(function() {
    $('.iframe-wrapper').append(iframeMarkup);
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/17knnLsb/3/

Comment: The problem here is that if anything changes inside that iframe - the change will not take effect after the show/hide, because you reload it.

Comment: I think this is much better. note that you don't really need the `z-index` and the `opacity` there.

Comment: Note that I'm not the one who asked this question. Just added my comment here :)

Comment: @Dekel Thanks for your comments. If the answer is correct you can vote it up :D

Comment: It will be great if you can add some source for what causes this behavior on chrome (is it a bug?)

Comment: I can't find any source for this issue, maybe it's a bug. I just tried other solutions without hiding.

Comment: MohammadReza and Dekel: Thanks for the workaround solution but if any you found why it happens like this only in Chrome browser means post it in comment. I hope it is bug in chrome browser.